# Number of sections of line bundles on a plane curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, line-bundles

Let $A$ be a line bundle of degree $1$ on a smooth plane quintic curve over complex numbers. We know that it can have at most $1$ section. My question is the following :

Under what conditions  it has one non-trivial section?Is it more often that it has no section?

Any insight from anyone is welcome

Comment: Line bundles with of degree 1 with a section on a curve $C$ are parameterized by the image of the canonical map $C \to Pic^1(C)$. So, they are parameterized by a 1-dimensional subvariety in a 6-dimensional abelian variety.

Comment: @Sasha, suppose we obtain this divisor on quintic curve as the restriction of the divisor on a quintic surface whose self intersection number is known. Then can we say anything about the number of sections of the line bundle on curve?